# Latex2rtf - command not found

Tags: latex2rtf

I am trying to run `latex2rtf` command, but I am getting

```
-bash: latex2rtf: command not found
```

How do I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`latex2rtf` is not installed in your system. You should install it using your package manager:

http://latex2rtf.sourceforge.net/usage.html see section 2.3